# Xcode 6.3 freezes when I quit the Main.storyboard

Tags: xcode, freeze, xcode6.3

I'm experiencing a very strange error: my Xcode is freezing when I quit a certain storyboard of a certain project.

When i open Xcode, the xib shows up normally, **I can even edit it and save it**. But when I'm trying to open another file, *any* other file, it freezes forever.

I tried to delete every temporary files as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247008/xcode-freezes-on-startup-while-loading-project), or [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/159609/18671), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203567/xcode-crashing-on-startup-possibly-due-to-too-many-open-projects), but the problem still remains. Ah, and... re-create my xib is obviously not an option...

Any other idea?

EDIT:

When I delete myProject/[project.xcworkspace/]xcuserdata (s), I can navigate in my project as usual while I don't open the storyboard. otherwise my problem comes again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my post about this problem, I saw it on other projects. I'm pretty sure this was linked to custom fonts in xib, because it often happened after an Xcode bug rendering custom fonts.

Few days ago I downloaded the last Xcode version, 6.3.2, and the problem did not bother me again. So it seems to be resolved.